# LinkedHashSet loop from some element onwards (Java).

Tags: java, loops, linkedhashset

I am using a LinkedHashSet in my code and at some point I need to iterate and run an algorithm in all the elements of the HashSet from an element onwards.

So if my set contains numbers 1,2,3,4,5. I want to start the loop from the 3 and not the 1. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Programmatically everything is possible, just with a if condition in your case. Are you in search of any API code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could copy it into an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) so that you might use [`subList(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29); and then you might use a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) like

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
for (Integer i : new ArrayList<>(set).subList(2, set.size())) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the same method to directly get an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) like

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
Iterator<Integer> iter = new ArrayList<>(set).subList(2, set.size())
        .iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iter.next());
}
```

Both output (the requested)

```
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two possible meanings to 'start the loop from 3'. You could mean you want only items that are equal or greater than 3 in the list. Or you could mean that you want to skip the first 2 items when sorted in a specific order. I would recommend you make your meaning explicitly clear in your code. If you are using Java 8 then streams provide a good mechanism to do this:

```
myHashSet.stream()
    .sorted(myComparator)
    .skip(2)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
myHashSet.stream()
    .filter(n -> n >= 3)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `TreeSet` instead of a `LinkedHashSet`, you could use the method [`tailSet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#tailSet(E)). If you use it this way: `mySet.tailSet(3)`, it will return a *view* of your set (that is also a `Set`), containing only `3, 4, 5`.